# Update multiple rows in single form laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a single page displaying multiple rows in the format of a spreadsheet.

inside of a foreach loop, I'm adding the ID to the start of each field, so In this case I'm trying to save all of the updated fields corresponding to there ID using AJAX.

I'm not sure of the best way to save multiple rows in one single form/map the data, 
E.g

```
 <input type="text" id="Portfolio" name="{{$bpp->id}}__Portfolio"
  data-row="{{$bpp->id}}" data-col="Portfolio" value="
 {{$bpp->Portfolio}}">
```

Returns the result of

1_Portfolio
 2_Portfolio
 3_Portfolio
 4_portfolio

I then need to save this into the row with the right ID.

If anyone has done this before some code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could try posting the data with input array

```html
<input type='text' name=id[] value='1'>
<input type='text' name=id[] value='3'>
<input type='text' name=id[] value='5'>

<input type='text' name=value[] value='150'>
<input type='text' name=value[] value='300'>
<input type='text' name=value[] value='50'>
```

Then in your laravel:

```
foreach ($request->id as $i => id) {
    $portfolio = Portifolio::where('id', id)->first();
    $portfolio->value = $request->value[$i];
    $portfolio->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **whereIn** method, read more about [Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

```
$sortOrder = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4];
$updateArray = ['Type' => 'B', 'param2' => ''];
$collection = Type::whereIn('id', $sortOrder);
$data = $collection->get();
$collection->update($updateArray);
```